# Create Collection<T> using reflection

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, reflection

I need to pass a `Collection<T>` of type `SharpSvn.SvnListEventArgs` to the  `svnClient.GetList` method. The type `T` needs to be resolved at run time, because this is used in  MSBuild inline task. The `GetList` method call throws run time error as

> The best overloaded method match for '`SharpSvn.SvnClient.GetList(SharpSvn.SvnTarget, out System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<SharpSvn.SvnListEventArgs>)`' has some invalid arguments

Below is a code snippet which I tried. How can I resolve this?

```
        System.Type t = svntask.GetType("SharpSvn.SvnListEventArgs");
    //System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.EventArgs> branchfolderlist = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.EventArgs>();

    System.Type genericType = typeof(System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<>);
    System.Type constructedType = genericType.MakeGenericType(t);

    var branchfolderlist = System.Activator.CreateInstance(constructedType);


    //branchfolderlist = svntask.GetType("SharpSvn.SvnListEventArgs")branchfolderlist;
    //System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Object> branchfolderlist;

    dynamic svnTarget = svntask.GetType("SharpSvn.SvnTarget").GetMethod("FromUri").Invoke(null, new object[] { new System.Uri(destinationBranch) });

    //svntask.GetType("SharpSvn.SvnClient").GetMethod("GetList").Invoke(null, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, new object[] { svnTarget, branchfolderlist }, null);

    svnClient.GetList(svnTarget, out branchfolderlist);

    return true;
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Try next time to get rid of unnecessary comments. This immensely improves the readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the declared type of `branchfolderlist` is `object`. Changing it to `dynamic` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, dynamic did resolve the issue for branchfolderlist. Now I have problem with svnTarget parameter, keep getting as in the original post. Not sure what could be the issue as I was able to pass svnTarget the same way in another method call. Will out parameter cause an issue?

Comment: It is the same error as before
The best overloaded method match for 'SharpSvn.SvnClient.GetList(SharpSvn.SvnTarget, out System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<SharpSvn.SvnListEventArgs>)' has some invalid arguments

if I change **svntarget** as **new SharpSvn.SvnTarget....** , then the above error goes off and get a different runtime error on binding...

That being said, since the original question is addressed, I'm marking your 1st response as answer.

Comment: @Karun: Can you please tell me the output for `svnTarget.GetType()` and `branchfolderlist.GetType()`? Please call them right before the call to `GetList`.